# How to generate string dynamically in Python (Observer Pattern)

Tags: python, string, dynamic, observer-pattern

Supposing we have the code below:

```
var1="top"
var2=var1+"bottom"
```

We want to change `var1` value if a condition is true:

```
if COND==True:
  var1="changed"
```

Now I want to have `var2` **dynamically changed**. With the code above, `var2` will still have the value "`topbottom`".

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Strings are immutable, so there can't be any such *dynamic change*, except you create a new string object using the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string formatting to specify a placeholder in `var2` where you want the updated value of `var1` to be placed:

```
In [1653]: var2 = '{}bottom'
```

The `{}` brackets here specify a placeholder. Then call [`var2.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting) to insert `var1` into `var2` as and when needed.

```
In [1654]: var1 = 'top'

In [1655]: var2.format(var1)
Out[1655]: 'topbottom'

In [1656]: var1 = 'changed'

In [1657]: var2.format(var1)
Out[1657]: 'changedbottom'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can elegantly achieve this with a callback proxy from [`ProxyTypes`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ProxyTypes/0.9) package:

```
>>> from peak.util.proxies import CallbackProxy
>>> var2 = CallbackProxy(lambda: var1+"bottom")
>>> var1 = "top"
>>> var2
'topbottom'
>>> var1 = "left"
>>> var2
'leftbottom'
```

Each time you access your `var2`, callback lambda will be executed and a dynamically generated value returned.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to do this as string are immutable in python. There is no way `var2` can be changed after `var1+"bottom"` evaluation. You either need to create a new string (not sure why do don't want to do this) or you need to write your own class and create your own objects that accept this behavior. If you want to do this, take a look at [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, since strings are immutable you must find a way to insert the dynamic value on the formation of the string.

I am a fan of the new 'fstrings' in Python- single line 'if' statement for flare:

```
cond = True

var1 = "changed" if cond is True else "top"
var2 = f"{var1} bottom"

print(var2)
```